# What is the use case for -M gcc option?

Tags: c, gcc, build

gcc's `-M` option gives makefile compatible list of dependencies. I've tried it on one of my projects `*.c` files and I got very long list of various system headers:

```
$ gcc -I/home/marko/foo/local/include -I/home/marko/foo/src/misc.git -M src/foo.c | wc -l
65
```

What is the use case for this? Why would anyone need such long list of not so useful dependencies? Or is it somehow used in autotools and not intended for manual use?

Comment: Why would that be useless? Just let `make` include  it and decide what's useful for it.

Comment: It's mainly used in conjunction with other options. Have a look at [the -M* options](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/gcc1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is primarily a pedantic thing.  You might want to track system dependencies for some reason.  For example, you might be using `-isystem` or `--sysroot` or something like that, and want your dependency tracking to work properly when you update the files in the sysroot.  Less likely, you might want your project to rebuild properly after you update the operating system.

I would hazard a guess that using `-M` is generally harmless.